# Changing the Javascript objects value in knock out js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a data variable which is in format of nested data structure

```
   var args = JSON.stringify({ argBO: jQuery.parseJSON(ko.toJSON(self.StateModel)) });
```

which will look like:

```
  {"argBO":
    { "StateId":0, 
    "StateName":"jjhj",
    "ShortName":"jjj",
    "IsActive":true,
    "CountryId":8,
    "errors":[],
    "CountryName":"Antigua and Barbud"
       }
  }
```

If try to get the StateName parameter value from above like:

```
  console.log(ko.utils.parseJson(args).argBO.StateName);
```

It is correctly printing "jjhj"

But if i try to assign a new value to it by doing:

```
  ko.utils.parseJson(args).argBO.StateName= 'RAjmsd'
```

StateName is not changing to new one.. Why????

**UPDATE:**

```
var stateModel = {
        StateId: ko.observable(0),
        StateName: ko.observable('').extend({ required: true }),
        ShortName: ko.observable('').extend({ required: true }),
        IsActive: ko.observable(true),
        CountryId: ko.observable().extend({ required: true })

    }
```

Comment: do you want to change the value in the stateModel or in the args variable

Comment: Ofcourse In Statemodel  but by using 'args'

Answer (score 0):

The second statement creates a new object and then changes the `StateName` property on that new object, but then you don't do anything with the object.

```
ko.utils.parseJson(args)
```

That code creates a brand new object by parsing the JSON string.  It has nothing to do with the original object.

It seems you have a reference to `self.StateModel` from looking at your code (although showing your complete view model would help), so you should just change the StateName directly via:

```
self.StateName('RAjmsd');
```

Comment: Show the code that is trying to execute the update on the view model.  Not just the single line of code, the complete "click" handler or whatever complete function you've written to try and update StateName.

Comment: i Tried using your method ,, but nothing helped!! self.StateName() is not a function!!

Comment: Complete code?? let me create a fiddle with my code so that u understand

Comment: Hi @Patrick I tried to give more more info on my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2K8Vy/